# Jitter and dodge points on boxplots with single factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to dodge boxplots, but for factors which only have single factor I want to
maintain same width as the other boxplots. The solution to that is to add `preserve="single" in the boxplot position.

At same time I would like to add jittered points over their respective boxplots. Therefore I need to jitter and dodge. `position_jitterdodge()` does what I need, but I am not sure how to dodge them
appropriately for the single factor boxplot

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=20), y=rnorm(20*3), z=c(rep(c("A","B"), times=20),rep("A",20)))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y,col=z)) + geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(0.85, preserve = "single")) + 
  geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(0.05))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=20), y=rnorm(20*3), z=c(rep(c("A","B"), times=20),rep("A",20)))
#Code
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,col=z)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge2(0.85, preserve = "single")) + 
  geom_jitter(position = position_dodge2(0.85, preserve = "single"))
```

Output:

[image]

Or this:

```
#Code 2
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,col=z)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge2(0.85, preserve = "single")) + 
  geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(0.05))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I guess that will do. For bonus points is there anyway to have the points and the boxplot dodge as in the original?

Comment: @bdeonovic I have added an update at the end, could you please check?

Comment: I think it would be good to specify the dodge width explicitly

Comment: @bouncyball You are welcome to edit the answer, and add what you mentioned :)